# Merge several XMLs and propagate changes

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

**Original question:**
I have 1000 of XMLs with a similar structure and I want to merge them into a master XML with the elements I need to translate. Once I have this master XML translated I want to propagate the changes back to the individual XMLs, so at the end I will have the 1000 XMLs translated.

I am clear on how to merge the XMLs using XSL, but the part to propagate the changes back it's what I'm struggling with.

Could you give any guidance on how would you do it?

**Edit2:**

So this what I have so far:

**Merging the XMLs**

Note that the XMLs may be completely different, this needs to be flexible in terms of XML structure.

```
Dim XML1 = XElement.Load("D:\xml1.txt")
Dim XML2 = XElement.Load("D:\xml2.txt")
//datasetXMLv2 contains a table Entry with 4 columns: number, Order, File, ContentXML)
//contentXML column is set as an object, all other columns are strings

DatasetXMLv2.Tables("Entry").Rows.Add(New Object() {"1", "order1", "file1", XML1})
DatasetXMLv2.Tables("Entry").Rows.Add(New Object() {"2", "order2", "file2", XML2})

DatasetXMLv2.Tables("Entry").WriteXml("d:\merge.xml")
```

**XML1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<item type="product">
    <key>Key1</key>
    <field><![CDATA[product name]]></field>
    <comment></comment>
</item>
```

**XML2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<item type="product">
    <key>Key2</key>
    <field><![CDATA[product name2]]></field>
    <desc><![CDATA[description2]]></desc>
    <comment></comment>
    <img>http://myimage</img>
</item>
```

**Merge.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<MergeXMLv2>
  <Entry>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Order>order1</Order>
    <File>file1</File>
    <XMLContent msdata:InstanceType="System.Xml.Linq.XElement, System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
      <item type="product">
        <key>Key1</key>
        <field><![CDATA[product name]]></field>
        <comment>
        </comment>
      </item>
    </XMLContent>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Order>order2</Order>
    <File>file2</File>
    <XMLContent msdata:InstanceType="System.Xml.Linq.XElement, System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
      <item type="product">
        <key>Key2</key>
        <field><![CDATA[product name2]]></field>
        <desc><![CDATA[description2]]></desc>
        <comment>
        </comment>
        <img>http://myimage</img>
      </item>
    </XMLContent>
  </Entry>
<MergeXMLv2>
```

As you can see, the **result from merging is satisfactory** as I have each XML mapped (in this example I have used file1 and file2 but it would have the actual xml1 and xml2 paths) to then extract the content stored in the XMLcontent node.

**Propagating the XMLs**

This is the part where I am struggling with. My code so far is as follows:

```
Dim mergeXML As XmlDocument
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim node As XmlNode
mergeXML = New XmlDocument

mergeXML.Load("D:\merge.xml")
nodelist = mergeXML.SelectNodes("//Entry")

For Each node In nodelist
    Dim nodeNumer = node.ChildNodes(0).InnerText
    Dim nodeOrder = node.ChildNodes(1).InnerText
    Dim nodeFile = node.ChildNodes(2).InnerText
    Dim nodeXMLcontent = node.ChildNodes(3).InnerText
Next
```

I'm missing the part to simply extract the content of the XMLcontent node to a separate XML using the Number, order, file nodes to replace the original files xml1.txt and xml2.txt.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the changes you make to the master XML this may be close to impossible - (a) why not transform each of the XMLs individually? (b) if you keep the output of the modified master XML nicely  formatted, you could just split it up at the points where you know that two files meet?

Comment: General purpose languages like Vb.Net can split the master XML by dynamically changing XSLT script or string to filter by needed sections, then iteratively save output to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these libraries

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Xml.Serialization
```

Code will be like

```
    Dim mergeXML As XmlDocument
    Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim node As XmlNode
    mergeXML = New XmlDocument

    mergeXML.Load("D:\merge.xml")
    nodelist = mergeXML.SelectNodes("//Entry")

    For Each node In nodelist
        Dim nodeNumber = node.ChildNodes(0).InnerText
        Dim nodeOrder = node.ChildNodes(1).InnerText
        Dim nodeFile = node.ChildNodes(2).InnerText
        Dim nodeXMLcontent = node.LastChild.FirstChild

        Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter("C:\ExtractedXML_" & nodeNumber & nodeOrder & nodeFile & ".txt")
        Dim x As New XmlSerializer(nodeXMLcontent.GetType)
        x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, nodeXMLcontent)
        objStreamWriter.Close()
    Next
```